# Custom static layout

Tags: cakephp, layout

i want to add static html page layout for my application (advanced search layout).

i would like that it will be accessed by url http://myapp/search

tryed to create custom controller (search_controller.php) and index view (view/search/index.ctp), but cake requires database table search.

also, followed info from

http://cake-php.blogspot.com/2006/09/21-things-you-must-know-about-cakephp.html

but no luck.

so, can you help me how to create custom layout in php.

thank you in advance!

Comment: A custom layout and a static page are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"tryed to create custom controller (search_controller.php) and index view (view/search/index.ctp), but cake requires database table search."

Not so - you can make the model table-less by using the class variable:

```
var $useTable = false;
```

If you don't wish to use a Model, in the controller set:

```
var $uses = array();
```

You should be able to manipulate the url using app/config/routes.php and/or .htaccess.